# pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts Modern Script Editor Webpart page reloading issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx-webparts, pnp-powershell, pnp

I'm using the Modern Script Editor Webpart from pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts GitHub. Installation and deployment all went fine and I can also execute JavaScript code on my sample modern teamsite.

Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let elem = document.querySelectorAll("[class='CanvasComponentWrapper']");
elem[0].style.maxWidth = '90%';
</script>
```

This code widens the canvas and it works as intended. However when I leave the homepage, going into Documents for exmaple, and navigate back to Home the script is not applied any longer.
On the other hand, if I click on Home once more in the Quick Launch nav it will reload the script.

So the behavior is: After leaving and returning to the page hosting the webpart/script the script is not reapplied unless the page was reloaded twice.

Any idea why that could be?

[image]

Thanks.

However, I noticed that

Comment: Which version are you running? I added a fix in April last year to re-trigger on smart navigation scenarios but might be it only works if you reference a script and not inline ones.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had installed the latest version 1.0.0.16. I added a .gif to demonstrate what's happening. Basically the CanvasComponent gets resized to 33% max-width. That works. However, if I clicka nav link to move into another library and go back home the script is no longer applied and the width is the default. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have repro, and seems to work as intented. I used the below which sets width of the header of a modern page. Alert is there to show it triggers on each navigation.

<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.querySelectorAll("[class='webPartContainer']");
elem[0].style.maxWidth = '80%';
alert('a');
</script>

Comment: Thanks for testing. So alert() always works even when coming back from another navigation node. However, applied styles don't like described. Can you test with hiding the site title?

`<script type="text/javascript">
let elem = document.querySelectorAll("span[role*='heading']");
elem[0].style.display = 'none';
</script>`
That also doesn't work but it should be easier for you to test. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine, but you have to replace "let" with "var", as let is not a JavaScript keyword. (Which I did the first time around as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `let` with `var` to have compliant JavaScript and it should work just fine.

Comment: That was it! Thanks and I apologize. Didn`t occur to me that this could have been the problem.